# How to Use ScrapingHub.com API to post data on Heroku database?

Tags: heroku, web-scraping, scrapy

How to Use ScrapingHub.com API to post data on Heroku database? I am thinking that is it possible to connect my API from scrapinghub to Heroku databe?

Any idea please? Please help me thank you!

Comment: One way to do this is to use Scrapy feed exports (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=FEED%20EXPORT#storages) and populate the base when a new file is created.

Comment: For sure! Also using [FormRequest](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-to-send-data-via-http-post) to make a HTTP POST.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure SHUB allows web-hooking ! Its been a while since I've used them but I recall it being a paid member feature.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hi @Gallaecio I am now trying this one https://doc.scrapinghub.com/api/items.html reading the docu provided by Shub, any suggestion?

Comment: You should share your current code, and let us know where, specifically, you got stuck. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for helping me I already solve my problem by using requirement dependency on scrapinghub :)